# Capture http request in my app built in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, http, webview, interceptor

I have created a simple web view app on android studio . I want to capture all the http requests it makes. Please suggest me some code or method . I dont want to use third party application like fiddler.
It should be some code to capture those request i made using the app.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything and you are stuck or receive an error message? If yes, can you please provide the code alongside with the error?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a third-party application?  What do you mean by "capture"?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to develop a code within my app like using some class so that it will give the output as all the request and response headers of the url i search in the web view app. I cant use third party application, its the part of my project.